# .highcharts-button-symbol image

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

Im trying to change my highcharts graphic symbol to a image.

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        contextButton: {
            symbol:'url(images/arrowdownwards.svg)',
            symbolX:19,
            symbolY:20
        }
    }
},
```

This works until the code is compiled then my image gets another name and it stops working.

what i want to know is if there is any way to pass a css in that parameter and how.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
.highcharts-button-symbol {
  display: none
}

.highcharts-contextbutton text {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
}

  "exporting": {
    "buttons": {
      "contextButton": {
        "enabled": true,
                text: "\ue059",
        width: 20

      }
    }
  },
```

this works